# Why does my cron execute once a day on aws elasticbeanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron

I'm wondering why this is only running once a day.  It should be running once every 5 minutes.

```
files:
    "/etc/cron.d/mycron":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            */5 * * * * root /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh

    "/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            #!/bin/bash

            #date > /tmp/date
            /usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null https://example.com/pull-shopify-orders
            /usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null https://example.com/getMexicoEngravedOrders
            exit 0

commands:
    remove_old_cron:
        command: "rm -f /etc/cron.d/mycron.bak"
```

Comment: How do you know it only runs once a day?  What are you checking?

Comment: I'm only going by the hit on my db.  Is there away I can monitor it or check in a log?  I can't seem to find any info on that.  @NateEldredge

Comment: On my system cron jobs are logged in `/var/log/syslog`; search for `CRON`.

Comment: What OS are you running, and what version of crond?  Some versions might need to be reloaded in some way in order to notice that the file in cron.d has changed.

Comment: Amazon Linux OS I'm not sure what version of cron.  @NateEldredge

Comment: Have you uncommented `#date > /tmp/date` and inspected /tmp/date file. You should find new entries every 5 minutes there.